# Dilemma with app.config - why can't I embed the application configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, startup

I have a application that must run on any plain Windows installation (from Vista up to 10).
On Vista you got framework 3.5, on Win10 there's framework 4.6 installed.
To run on both, the application must target different frameworks.
Therefore I made use of multiple [`supportedRuntime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx) entries in `app.config`, which makes this possible - works perfect.

Now I got a second problem, I have to ship `app.config` together with the application.
This **is** a problem, because of the way the application is distributed, `app.config` can get lost and the whole thing blows up.

So the idea was to embed `app.config` into the executable, against the principle of the file "user should be able to change it".
In this case, the user should **not** be able to change it, because it would no longer work.

Here's what I found so far:
[How do you embed app.config in C# projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846975)
[How do I compile my App.config into my exe in a VS2010 C# console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586210)
The essence is 'you can't do that'.

**So the question is:**
Is there either a way to embed `app.config` or is there another way to specify `supportedRuntime` somewhere else than `app.config`?

There seems to be no [compiler switches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx) that addresses the configuration.
Are there further tools to manipulate the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late.
I use 7zip Self-Extract feature to create an archive that will extract itself in the user's temp folder and run a specified exe.  That way you can have your exe and your app.config together.