# Ship config inside .dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, app-config

I have few config values which are static and not going to change frequently for my DLL project. I can add those config values in ProjectName.dll.config.

But then I have to ship  ProjectName.dll.config with my ProjectName.dll. Also, I have to inform .dll consumers about this new config file (or change .dll consumers build code).

Is there a way I can store these config values in .dll itself? So I don't need to worry about shipping config files?

Comment: You could embed the file as a resource. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846975/how-do-you-embed-app-config-in-c-sharp-projects

Comment: What's the purpose of having a config file then, you can have your "config data" directly inside dll file, written in some static class.

Comment: @SᴇM could you please direct me to some example / blog? For more readability and maintainability?