Build c# project to single file with embedded config
I need to insert values from app.config to program variables and build my c# project to single file.
Example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="A" value="123" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("A");

But when I building project i got .exe file and app.config file.
I need only .exe with app.config embedded.
Can I achieve that?

A similar answer has been provided. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862657/c-sharp-app-config-embedded-resource-in-visual-studio

string a = "A"; - if your config is "embedded" then it is also immutable. Which in turn means you can as well hard-code the value you want / need. Except you want to have "embedded default config" ... which may (or may not) be modified by the user in which case it will be written to the filesystem?

What's the point of embedding the application config in the final exe file? You're defeating the point of a config file. Why not use #if directives and hard code the config values into the code?

@Fildor The point is that I have a builder that will generate app.config with special values and build the app. Is there another way to achieve this?

How are these special values being generated?  Do you really need an additional step of generating them to file?  Instead of generating them straight into your config variables within the app?  You really only have 2 choices for mutable configuration - internal and external.  Internal usually utilizes compile time build directives as gunr pointed out.  External is either database or file.  You don't want a file, so you're limited to database for loading values at run time.

I have a builder that will generate app.config with special values and build the app - you might as well get it to generate you a .cs file then, rather than a xyz.json - it then compiles to become part of the app

Extraordinary build processes need extraordinary explanation in the question. You didn't even mention that. How do you expect to get a useful answer leaving out such a decisive part of your system?
